# infinite image looping across screen

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

still pretty new at javascript and nextjs, and I am struggling to create a continuous loop of an image that goes across the screen (mobile, tablet only).
** if you go to wevise.org and view mobile size you'll see what I am trying to recreate.
Here is the html code

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>

      <div className='flex justify-center mt-7 text-xl'>
        <p>Trusted talent from top companies</p>
      </div> 

      <div className='lg:ml-[14rem] lg:mr-[14rem]'>
        <Image src={img} alt='img' className='flex justify-center w-[100%] h-[6.5rem]' />
      </div>

     </div>
  )
}
```

Where do I go from here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code of the site that you shared to get the idea how it works. A few notes I see looking into the html/css at that site:

They use a dom structure like the one below, that means that all the images have `absolute` position and basically are positioned one above the other.

```
<div class="absolute">
  <img class="absolute opacity-0">
  <img class="absolute opacity-0">
  <img class="absolute opacity-1">
</div>
```

Also you might notice that most of the images have `opacity: 0` (that makes them invisible) but the image that should be visible has `opacity: 1`;

So, basically to repeat that functionality I think you need to write a javascript code that will change the opacity of previously displayed image to 0, and sets opacity to 1 for the next image in the queue.

To run code periodically with a delay look at `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functionality. And to find all the images you can use `document.querySelectorAll`

And one more thing, to make it visible only on mobile you need to use `media query` CSS functionality, for example they use it like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.md\:hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Which means, to display the elements with `.md:hidden` class only when screen size is smaller than `768`